# Applescript move to a new folder with sequential naming

Tags: applescript, subdirectory

I've a written the below basic script that checks to see if a folder exists and if it does takes the contents of that folder and adds it to a subfolder.

as you can see in this script generates the sub folder named V1, I wondered if there was a way to sequential name nd generate new folders?

e.g if folder V1 exists Create V2 and move contents

Current Script

```
--Set image source folder
set SourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Base Images:")
set Sourcefoldertext to SourceFolder as text
set FoldertoReplace to Sourcefoldertext & "Images:"

tell application "Finder
    if (exists folder named "Images" in folder SourceFolder) then make new folder in folder FoldertoReplace with properties {name:"V1"}
    if (exists folder named "Images" in folder SourceFolder) then set fileList to every file of folder FoldertoReplace  
    if not (exists folder named "Images" in folder SourceFolder) then make new folder in folder SourceFolder with properties {name:"Images"}    
    if (exists folder named "V1" in folder FoldertoReplace) then set VersionFolder to the folder named "V1" in the folder FoldertoReplace   
    if (exists folder named "V1" in folder FoldertoReplace) then return move the fileList to the VersionFolder'
end tell
```

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing solution is great, but I thought I'd add an alternative just for some variety.

This handler uses *System Events* and a recursive function call to check for existing folder versions.  The parameter `targetFolderPath` can be an `alias` object, a posix path, or an HFS path.

```
to createSequentialVersionFolder at targetFolderPath given name:dir : "V"
    local targetFolderPath, dir

    script
        property fp : targetFolderPath
        property dirname : dir

        to checkVersion(i)
            tell application "System Events"
                if exists the folder named (dirname & i) ¬
                    in the folder named fp then ¬
                    return my checkVersion(i + 1)

                make new folder at folder named fp ¬
                    with properties ¬
                    {name:dirname & i}
            end tell
        end checkVersion
    end script

    result's checkVersion(1)
end createSequentialVersionFolder
```

To use:

```
createSequentialVersionFolder at "~/Desktop"
```

or:

```
createSequentialVersionFolder at (path to desktop folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this handler, it creates a new folder with sequential name and returns the Finder reference to the new created folder

```
on createSequentialVersionFolder(targetFolderPath)
    set counter to 1
    repeat
        set versionFolder to "V" & counter
        tell application "Finder"
            if not (exists folder versionFolder in folder targetFolderPath) then
                make new folder at folder targetFolderPath with properties {name:versionFolder}
                return result
            end if
        end tell
        set counter to counter + 1
    end repeat
end createSequentialVersionFolder
```

Your other code contains a lot of redundant stuff. It can be reduced to

```
set Sourcefolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose Base Images:") as text
set FoldertoReplace to Sourcefolder & "Images:"

tell application "Finder"
    if exists folder FoldertoReplace then 
        set versionFolder to my createSequentialVersionFolder(FoldertoReplace)
        set fileList to every file of folder FoldertoReplace
        move the fileList to the versionFolder
    else 
        make new folder in folder SourceFolder with properties {name:"Images"}
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works perfectly!! Ive amended to your'e simplified version as well.
Thanks again P